# Return same value mutiple times in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return a value acquired from the following function

```
function score(string,pattern)
{  
  counter=0
  for(i=0;i<string.length;i++)
  {
    if(string.toUpperCase().substr(i,pattern.length) == pattern.toUpperCase())
      counter++
  }   
  return counter  
}
```

into the following array

```
result=[]

for(i=0;i<web.length;i++){
  result[result.length]=score("Coooool!","OO")
  }
```

such that `result=4,4,4` currently, `result=4`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: try pushing to the array instead.

Comment: As @KevinKloet commented: use `.push()`: `result.push(score("what","ever"));`

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You should also consider removing the score function from the question; it is not relevant at all. [Correction: it seems to matter that the value doesn't change, I didn't edit the question though.]

Comment: I have rolled back your edit as definition of `score` is required

Comment: @KevinKloet Issue was with variable declaration. Missing `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is, when you define variables without `var`, they become part of global scope.

#### Your Code

```js
function score(string, pattern) {
  counter = 0
  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string.toUpperCase().substr(i, pattern.length) == pattern.toUpperCase())
      counter++
  }
  return counter
}

result = []

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log("Before call: ", i)
  result[result.length] = score("Coooool!", "OO")
  console.log("After call: ", i)
}

console.log(result)
```

#### Resolved Code

```js
function score(string, pattern) {
  var counter = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string.toUpperCase().substr(i, pattern.length) == pattern.toUpperCase())
      counter++
  }
  return counter
}

var result = []

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  result[result.length] = score("Coooool!", "OO")
}

console.log(result)
```

Also as rightly pointed out by [kevin kloet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5547818/kevin-kloet), you should use `.push` instead of `result[result.length]`

Comment: In the resolved code, if i remove the `var` before `i` in the `score` function, I'm right back at `[4]`. Why is this happening?

Comment: It will update `i` in external `for` as well. variables are hoisted. So `var i` will move at top and for would look like `for(i=0; i<4; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing your array based on the length rather than the counter. So change it to `result[i]=...` like below.

```
result=[]

for(i=0;i<web.length;i++){
    result[i]=score("Coooool!","OO")
}
```

You could also `push` to the array:

```
result=[]

for(i=0;i<web.length;i++){
    result.push(score("Coooool!","OO"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however both solutions still makes result=4

Comment: what is the length of `web` when you do `console.log(web.length)`?

Comment: What does `web` look like?

Comment: result=[0,0,0]

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  result[i]=score("Coooool!","OO")
  }    seems to return 4,0,0, not 4,4,4